# Cannot edit maintenance plan?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

Using SQL Server 2019 standard.

I know I previously was able to edit maintenance plans - I added a line to them last week to run a stored procedure on a new schema (it was already called on other schemas.

Now though, when I open the maintenance plan, I am trying to comment out the line I added last week because there's some issues I need to trouble shoot, and I can't seem to.  The OK button stays grey no matter what, if I comment out my line, delete the line, add a new line, etc.

I looked at my roles using the following query

```
select r.name as Role, m.name as Principal

from

    master.sys.server_role_members rm

    inner join

    master.sys.server_principals r on r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id and r.type = 'R'

    inner join

    master.sys.server_principals m on m.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id

where m.name = 'someCompany\MyName'
```

and it says I am a sysadmin so I would think that means I have all the privileges to do this but no matter what the OK stays grey.  I've tried exiting SSMS, restarting my computer, making sure I right click "Modify" on the Maintenance Plan and then right-click "Edit" on the specific sub plan but no matter what it's greyed out.  I am at the end of things to try.  Anyone know what is going wrong here?  I'm sure it's something simple I am missing but it's been 2 hours now and I can't justify not asking for help on this anymore.

Edit: Some clarifications based on comments:
My role of sysadmin was determined based on the query above which I found in another post.

I am referring to a TSQL Task inside a maintenance subplan.  This task calls several stored procedures, one of which I added last week by typing it in and clicking OK.  Now, I cannot seem to comment out that stored procedure, delete it, or add another stored procedure - the OK button remains disabled regardless.

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: @J.D. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

Comment: What exact build number though?

Comment: @J.D. SQL Server Management Studio 18.12.1, Version 15.0.18424.0.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: For the benefit of other readers, I recommends you to clarify a few things by editing your post above. You say "comment out the line". Where? I assume this is  in a Task, if so, what task type (I'm guessing execute T-SQL, but we want to avoid guesses)? Also what stays grey? The OK button for the task you are editing or something else? Also "it says I'm a sysadmin". Exactly what is "it" in this context?

Comment: @TiborKaraszi Sorry this is not a part of SQL Server I have dealt with much before.  There is a maintenance plan, and within that, are sub plans, within the subplans I see Jobs that are run in the subplan that are the `Transact T-SQL` type where it calls stored procedures.  I am trying to comment out one of those stored procedures that I added last week, but the OK button to edit it remains grey when I modify it by commenting out my last one.  Trying to adding another line of stored procedures also does not enable the OK button, it's perpetually grey no matter how I edit the T-SQL statement.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi The sysadmin comment was about the result of my user roles based on the query above where I found elsewhere to figure out my permissions level.  I guess what I may be calling a job is actually a task?  It's a little box inside the sub plan of the maintenance plan, double clicking on it I can see the stored procedures it runs.  The little box in subplan portion says `Execute TSQL on Local server connection` and some other information regarding time zones.  I don't know if it matters but these jobs/tasks run every 2 minutes.